# How to upload a text/XML file to a web service

Tags: c#, .net

I have a web service URL which has username and password authentication mode. I have to first pass the username and password, and if I am authenticated, I can upload a text or XML file onto the server. I am looking for a C# code to do the same process, but I'm unable to find it.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

I am using following code-

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtfile))
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
                request.KeepAlive = false;
                request.SendChunked = true;
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                request.Method = "Post";
                request.ContentType = "text/xml";
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
                var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
                var data = encoder.GetBytes(txtfile);
                request.ContentLength = data.Length;
                var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                reqStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                reqStream.Close();
                WebResponse response = null;
                response = request.GetResponse();
                var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());                   

            }
```

Comment: show your method that accepts the file parameter

Comment: You can add your own parameters to the SOAP header.

Comment: Please see the code i have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try using the [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh.aspx). There is a simple example about the [WebClient.UploadFile Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esst63h0.aspx) which could fit your scenario.